# Can't add "MidiParser" pod to Podfile

Tags: cocoapods

I am trying to add this github project to my project as a pod: https://github.com/matsune/MidiParser

In my PodFile, I have tried

```
pod 'MidiParser'
```

and

```
pod 'MidiParser', :git => 'https://github.com/matsune/MidiParser.git'
```

but either time I get the error

```
Unable to find a specification for 'MidiParser'.
```

I have tried adding other pods like 'https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP' just to see if they work, and they do.  I notice there are multiple projects on GitHub called MidiParser, so maybe I need to distinguish between them somehow?  The installation instructions in the MidiParser README only give instructions for Carthage.  It says to add this line to the Cartfile:

```
github "matsune/MidiParser"
```

I also have also tried:

```
pod 'matsune/MidiParser'
```

I notice I can't find the project when I search for it here: https://cocoapods.org.
Does that mean I simply can't install the project using Cocoapods, and that I have to do it manually?

**Edit**: I ended up using Carthage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaPods requires pods to be specified with a podspec to describe its Xcode workspace integration.  See https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html